# Windows or Linux Ogg Rip Program with Album Art?

Tags: ripping, album-art, vorbis

I have a number of ogg and mp3 files with some tags, but basically it's a mess.  What I'd like to do is the following:

1. Get their tags right
2. Get their album art embedded in them so it shows up on my Android phone
3. I am willing to re-rip them if necessary.
4. If re-ripping is what I have to do, I want to insert the CD, have the program find the art and tracks, and hit "go" and it's embedded and tagged correctly (Amarok's option doesn't do this correctly, the art doesn't appear in Android's Play Music).

I couldn't find a good program for this that's free.  [Bliss](http://www.blisshq.com) for windows seems possible, but is pay for anything beyond "fixing" 100 songs.  [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com), also for windows, seems like it would be OK for what I want, but isn't on Linux either, which I'd like as an option.

Some other answers on here (like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/567839/universally-fix-re-embed-embedded-album-art)) aren't automatic and require you to find all your album art first and are somewhat manual.  Which doesn't help my tagging issue either.

Any solutions out there that "just work" that I'm missing?  Even if my existing library is hooped, shouldn't there be an easy solution that's just "insert CD, rip to ogg/vorbis" and it just works?

Or is my problem on the Android side in that Google's default player doesn't work like this?  How do I confirm that my file has or doesn't have the art embedded?  Do I need to slap Amarok?

Comment: What about Windows Media Player? There is no OGG support, but you can rip CD to wma to get really pretty album art and tags and convert all to ogg.

Comment: Ogg is required.  And if I'm doing a 2-step process, I need to be able to preserve the art, so I'd need a tool for that.

Comment: This is probably more on topic for Software recommendations - any objections to moving it over there in lieu of closing it?

Comment: That's fine.  I didn't know about that sub-forum.  And given that there were similar questions here, I thought maybe this was the place.  I'm OK with you moving it there.

Answer (score 0):

[Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) should let you fix up tags manually, and retrieve album art.

It works best when there's some sort of order, since you can convert filenames (and paths) to tags, and you can retrieve album art from amazon, or redo all the tagging with musicbrainz (which works alright in some cases, but not in others. Musicbrains is cool, but needs supervision). I'd strongly recommend batching up the conversion to avoid human error, but I've used this on music collections that's *thousands* of tracks with pretty decent accuracy.

Its *semi-automatic* - it just searches for the album title, and relies on you finding the right one by eye.

If you're ripping it from scratch, I recommend the *excellent* (though slightly oddly esoteric) [cuetools](http://www.cuetools.net/wiki/Main_Page). It automatically downloads album art, does error checking against a database, and for most part, is the best free (and is arguably better than most paid - it basically ticks off every feature on hydrogen audio's [comparison chart](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Comparison_of_CD_rippers#Comparison_chart)) option for ripping a cd. Its portable, so it *may* run on wine.